# pdb - What does the output mean?

Tags: python, pdb

`test.py`:

```
def fun():
    print 'Function'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fun()
```

`$ python -m pdb test.py`:

```
> /home/h/CARDIO/WorkSpace/PDB/test.py(4)<module>()
-> def fun():
(Pdb) n
> /home/h/CARDIO/WorkSpace/PDB/test.py(7)<module>()
-> if __name__ == '__main__':
(Pdb) n
> /home/h/CARDIO/WorkSpace/PDB/test.py(8)<module>()
-> fun()
(Pdb) n
Function
--Return--
> /home/h/CARDIO/WorkSpace/PDB/test.py(8)<module>()->None
-> fun()
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> <string>(1)<module>()->None
(Pdb) n
The program finished and will be restarted
```

1. What does the `<module>` and  `->None` refer to ?
2. It seems `fun()` took two `n` to finish. `fun()` is a single statement, shouldn't `n` step one statement at a time ? Why does `fun()` take two `n`?
3. I really don't know the meaning of `--Return--  > <string>(1)<module>()->None`. Not a single word or sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. None is the return value of your function. Module is is the function which returned which in your case is the actual module.
2. The first occurrence of `->def fun():` is where the function gets defined. The second one it got called.
3. I don't now why the signature of your module looks like this. It might be because you are debuging it and it's run inside pdb.